# Why do I get "Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount" when I try to mount my NTFS drive?

Tags: mount, ntfs

I have trouble with mounting my hard disk:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda5 at /media/quetzalcroix/DataSave: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda5" "/media/quetzalcroix/DataSave"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I forgot to restart my windows 8 before I'm installing Ubuntu and format my `C:\` drive. Is there any other options that I could do to mount this? Or I should backup my entire volume to other media and then I format my hard drive?

Comment: Can't you restart into Windows now?

Answer (score -1):

Try mounting it like this (if you haven't already):

```
mount -o ro /dev/sda5
```

Comment: Assuming this succeeds, it will mount it readonly. Depending on the OP's needs, that may or may not be a good solution (but it's a valuable one to know about, and often better than nothing if it works). If this doesn't work *or read-write access is necessary*, [the full solution is here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation).

Comment: @EliahKagan this answer is already in the duplicated.